# Line art, how to show the hidden edges? those which usually are dotted in technical drawings

Tags: 2d, lineart

I am trying to replicate this (Which is shown in the blender 3.3 release):
[image]

[see release Blender 3.3](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-3/)

But I have been activating random checks to achieve it, this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: This actually looks correct to me. What’s wrong?

Comment: @TheLabCat The red dotted lines are made by hand pencil, I am trying to get them from the LineArt modifier at render. In the first image, I have pointed to the desired with a red arrow in the second image I have added with red what should be shown but is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is what you are looking for:

1. Add > Grease Pencil > Object Line Art (and select the cube as the target Object)
2. In the modifiers Tab go to chaining and check Intersection With Contour (if you want to show where the geometry well... intersects).
3. Add another Object Line Art, but this time check Range under Occlusion, and then set the start and end levels to your desired goal.
4. Under the second line art add a Dot Dash modifier to get that effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Vagabonk's answer, you can use a Simplify modifier with Mode set to Sample and Influence only on the second line art to even the spacing between dashes. Otherwise all of your lines may have exactly the same number of dots or dashes.